# Interface Configuration in Arista EOS

Tags: networking, configuration, interface, switch-statement, router

I am trying to configure the Ethernet interfaces in an Arista Switch that is running on a vm (using vmware workstation). I am able to configure the management interface according to the user guid given but during configuring ethernet interfaces using the same procedure i am getting the following error:

```
localhost(config-if-Eth1)# ip address 172.16.204.4/24
! IP configuration will be ignored while interface Ethernet1 is not a routed port.
```

If someone could provide some help in this regard.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interface was in switchport mode.
running `no switchport` on ethernet 1 solved the issue.